Can probability density of super electrons in superconductors be greater than one?

This is related to Ginzburg Landau theory of phase transition in superconductors. Here the number density of super electron is taken as probability density, which would be always greater than one, and if we integrate it over a volume greater than one will give me probability greater than one which is not possible. What am I missing here?

Where is it interpreted this way? The word probability appears nowhere in the passage you included, nor in the wiki article you linked

A dimensionless 1 cannot be a spatial density, since you'd get a volume if you integrated it over space, while probability must be dimensionless, not have a dimension of volume.

I agree that the term probability is not used. However Mod Psi^2 is defined as probability density in QM. The QM wave function have been used to represnt Cooper pairs. The amplitude in the wave function is taken as square root of number density of superelectrons.
